# Scheduling background tasks ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My model structure has three models-test template,test instance and metrics
test template allows people to create the basic template for the tests and the instance spawns the test thread.. each test thread will have a set of metrics.. after this i need to schedule the tests every day at certain intervals of time (Background task).. Do i have to create a new schedule table and get the scheduling done and spawn new instances at each points of time or is there any other way ?

I am currently getting the schedule for the tests through the test instance model itself but cannot schedule test because each test instance will have only one metric.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever/) to be very useful when scheduling background tasks.

Comment: I am still a bit new to rails.. I did use whenever for one of my previous modules and it seemed to work fine.But I read somewhere that you cannot trigger frequent tasks as rake tasks and to integrate the module into my rails app i need to be able to frequently schedule background tests and need to be able to report the metric to the user..

Comment: You can get whenever to run every minute, which is pretty frequent!  Instead of `every 3.hours do ... end` try `every '* * * * *' do ... end` in your `schedule.rb`